# How do I replace the MuiTouchRipple-child background class from a listItem button?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The library is fantastic congratulations.

How do I replace the MuiTouchRipple-child background class from a listItem button?

Thank you.

```
<List component="nav">
                        <ListItem  button component="a" href="#simple-list">
                            <ListItemText primary="Trash" secondary="Jan 9, 2014" />
                        </ListItem>
                        <Divider />
                        <ListItem button component="a" href="#simple-list" >
                            <ListItemText primary="Spam" secondary="Jan 9, 2014" />
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work.
I have used TouchRippleProps

Answer (score 0):

Pass a classes object through TouchRippleProps:

```
TouchRippleProps={{ classes: { child: classes.rippleClasses } }}
```

JSS:

```
  rippleClasses: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
```